# How to use IF function within APPLY function in R?

Tags: r, loops, apply

These are commands showing the position of a man who walks randomly in four directions (Using the FOR LOOP is not allowed):

```
mat=matrix(c(1,0,0,1,-1,0,0,-1,0,0),ncol=2,byrow=T)
plot(apply(replicate(100,mat[sample(1:5,1),]),1,cumsum),type='l')
```

I'd like to limit the plot box for example between (-5,5) in both X and Y axis, so that when the man arrive at this limitations, he should continue walking without passing the limitation (I mean, continue in other three directions). But I don't know where to place the IF condition!

Comment: please use the [r] tag for questions about R and the [rstudio] tag ONLY if it pertains to the interface that the RStudio team have put around the language.